# Is there a NotReadyFunction in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, ready

Is it possible to check if the document is not ready and execute a function periodically in jQuery?

Simply I would like to achieve something like :

```
$('document').isNotReady(function(){

    $('#divState').text('Still Loading');  
});

$('document').Ready(function(){

    $('#divState').text('Loaded');
});
```

Is there a built-in function in jQuery to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just append the div at the top of the page with the loading text and when the document is ready change the text to loaded.

***Edit***

As @James pointed out, there is a problem with your selector. You are using divState as a tag selector, which won't be valid. Either you can use an id selector or a class selector in this case like

`$("#divState")` or `$(".divState")`

```
$(function(){
    $('#divState').text('Loaded');
});
```

Comment: +! just think the other way round!

Answer (score 1):

**HTML part:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="example_ajax_request()" value="Click Me!" />
<div id="example-placeholder">
  <p>Placeholding text</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery part:**

```
function example_ajax_request() {
  $('#example-placeholder').html('<p><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" width="220" height="19" /></p>');
  $('#example-placeholder').load("/examples/ajax-loaded.html");
}
```

**Source:** http://www.electrictoolbox.com/load-content-jquery-ajax-loading-image/

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I am aware. You could easily immidate it though:

```
var bIsReady = false;

$('document').Ready(function(){ 
    bIsReady = true;
    $('divState').text('Loaded'); 
}); 

/*
    use bIsReady somehow
/*
```

But I'm not sure why you would want to when you could just set it in the HTML:

```
<div>Still Loading</div>
```

And then change it as per your code above when the document is ready.

Also, if there was some NotReady function, you couldn't guarantee that the DIV you were setting was actually ready.

Also, you are selecting an element called DivState. Do you maybe mean: `$('#DivState')` ?